# Adding the value of a What If Parameter to a time value in Power BI

Tags: time, powerbi, dax

Using a what if statement in Power BI, I'm looking to use the value of the parameter to add minutes to a time value.

For example a time of 12:05, I would like to use a slider to add minutes to it so a value of 3 would result in a time of 12:08. Using the measure given by the parameter doesn't update the time field.

I have tried converting the time value to a whole number and vice versa but still no result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should put some code in here for us to look at.

Comment: For datetime values in Power BI, a single unit of time is a full day. So you'd need to divide your minute integer by 24*60 = 1440 to convert to days.